# No merge tables in MariaDB - options for very large tables?

Tags: merge, myisam, mariadb

I've been happily using MySQl for years, and have followed the MariahDB fork with interest.

The server for one of my projects is reaching end of life and needs to be rehosted - likely to CentOS 7, which includes MariahDB

One of my concerns is the lack of the merge table feature, which I use extensively.  We have a very large (at least by my standards) data set with on the order of 100M records/20 GB (with most data compressed) and growing.  I've split this into read only compressed myisam "archive" tables organized by data epoch, and a regular myisam table for current data and inserts.  I then span all of these with a merge table.

The software working against this database is then written such that it figures out which table to retrieve data from for the timespan in question, and if the timespan spans multiple tables, it queries the overlying merge table.

This does a few things for me:

- Queries are **much** faster against the smaller tables - unfortunately, the index needed for the most typical query, and preventing duplicate records is relatively complicated
- Frees the user from having to query multiple tables and assemble the results when a query spans multiple tables
- Allowing > 90% of the data to reside in the compressed tables saves alot of disk space
- I can back up the archive tables once - this saves tremendous time, bandwidth and storage on the nightly backups

An suggestions for how to handle this without merge tables?  Does any other table type offer the compressed, read-only option that myisam does?

I'm thinking we may have to go with separate tables, and live with the additional complication and changing all the code in the multiple projects which use this database.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB 10 introduced the [CONNECT storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/connect/) that does a lot of different things.  One of the table types it provides is [TBL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/connect/connect-table-types/connect-table-types-tbl-table-type-table-list/), which is basically an expansion of the MERGE table type.  The TBL CONNECT type is currently read only, but you should be able to just insert into the base tables as needed.  This is probably your best option but I'm not very familiar with the CONNECT engine in general and you will need to do a bit of experimentation to decide if it will work.

Comment: Thanks - I'm looking in to it.  It also seems like maybe MariahDB does handle myisam merge tables - just not merge tables for the newer storage engines.  Hope to get a test server up soon to try it out.